# Android Studio getting values from radio button, and using it elsewhere

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got the code below, to use a radio button and get the value and return it as a string for a function. Hoping that I could use it elsewhere in the main program. However, it doesn't. it would allow me to use the variable `btn` and if, I did the `atl-enter` suggestion by declaring it to `final string []`, it'll return null. Most online tutorial and stackoverflow previous question only includes toasting text from whichever button chosen, within `onCheckedChanged`.

```
public String listeneronbutton() {
        String btn;
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedID) {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedID);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btn = String.valueOf(radioButton.getText());      //(error here: variable 'btn' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final)
            }
        });
        return btn;
}
```

How do I get the function `listeneronbutton()` properly being able to get and return `btn` value?

Comment: I think error in toast radioButton.getText() replace by radioButton.getText().toString()

Comment: and you are use the value of radiobutton enywhere else by listeneronbutton()

Comment: I don't think it's the replacing issue since i couldn't  even assign the string to btn. And yes, I'm trying to get the string to be used by other function by calling listeneronbutton()

Comment: I just added code please try

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have a method which adds the `OnCheckedChangeListener` and gets the `String`, at the same time (because separation of duties & the one method only should run once, the other method more often). alike this you can add method `instanceRadioGroup()` to `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` and then get the current value with method `getButtonText()`.

also, the variable `int checkedId` is already being passed into the scope, so one can use that.

```
/** the handle for the {@link RadioGroup} */
private RadioGroup mRadioGroup = null;

/** this field holds the button's text */
private String mButtonText = null;

/** the setter for the field */
protected void setButtonText(@Nullable String value) {
    this.mButtonText = value;
}

/** the getter for the field */
protected String getButtonText() {
    return this.mButtonText;
}

/** it sets mButtonText by checkedId */
protected void updateButtonText(int checkedId) {
    if ((checkedId == -1)) {
        this.setButtonText(null);
    } else {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) this.mRadioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
        this.setButtonText(radioButton.getText());
    }
}

/** this code should only run once, onCreate() or onCreateView() */
protected void instanceRadioGroup() {

    /* setting the handle for the {@link RadioGroup} */
    this.mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    /* update the field with the text of the default selection */
    int checkedId = this.mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    this.updateButtonText(checkedId);

    /* and also add an onCheckedChange listener */
    this.mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
            updateButtonText(checkedId);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where should 
    `private String buttonText = null;`
be declared?

Comment: @fieq.fikri this is a private field of the class; eg. an `Activity` or a `Fragment`... adding `null` to the declaration simply ensures, that it has any value, instead of not being initialized at all... an improvement would be, to update it the the first selected checkbox text.

Comment: @fieq.fikri now the filed even gets initialized with the default selected button text... please accept when having tried it, more proper is barely possible (especially without using an IDE).

Comment: cool, I'll try if this works. Thanks a lot for being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method like this :

```
public String listeneronbutton() {
    String btn;
    RadioGroup radioGroup =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedID);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    btn = String.valueOf(radioButton.getText());      

    return btn;
}
```

Comment: This works on it's own but did not instantly change whenever a button is clicked. Since it's missing `onCheckedChanged()`. But, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Declare `String btn` as field. Thus you can access anywhere inside class.

```
public class Test{
    String btn;
    public String listeneronbutton(){

        return btn;
    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, I couldn't assign, btn = String.valueOf(radioButton.getText())